# Variable Unresolved reference

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables, kivy

I have a problem in my code i want to count a variable ervery time when i push a button. When i define the variable inside the function from the button than the function executed when somebody push the button and the variable set by every push to zero.To avoid this i set the variable outside from the function but i get the error:

`Unresolved reference`

And here is my code:

```
class myLayout(FloatLayout):
    CokkieAnzahl = 0
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.numeric_var = 1

    def on_button_clicked(self):
        CokkieAnzahl += 1
        self.ids.CokkieZahl.text = CokkieAnzahl
```

CokkieAnzahl is the variable.

Ps: I am still studend pls foregiv me my bad englisch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `self.CookieAnzahl`.

`CookieAnzahl += 1` mean `CookieAnzahl = CookieAnzahl + 1`, but since `CookieAnzahl` is **NOT** defined in `on_button_clocked()`'s **scope**, then it fails.